# Gradle build failed : Cannot create directory /home/vassar/.android/build-cache/3.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a new project.

Getting `Cannot create directory /home/vassar/.android/build-cache/3.4.0` error.

I tried Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to take ownership of the directory: `sudo chown -R vassar:vassar /home/vassar/.android`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.android
```